# confused with the JSON data from google geocoding api

Tags: java, android, json, api, geocoding

I'm making a weather app for android and am a bit new to using JSON data. I've already gotten the user's longitude and latitude in the app and am trying to use the google geocoding api to get the city and state/country name from that data. If you look at some [sample data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-place-id), you'll see that under address components there are multiple different sets of "long_name" and "short_name" as well as a "type" key. I know I should use the type key to identify which long_name I want to use, but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

p.s. My app is for android so I'm using java.